# Copy a directory structure including files from one remote machine to another using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I want to copy a directory recursively from one remote machine to another remote machine with Python, probably using paramiko.

I am looking for something similar to the following scp command, but using python instead:

```
scp user@10.3.0.1:/path/to/file user@10.3.0.2/path/to/file
```

Answer (score -1):

Run this command from the machine where u want to copy these file(not from source machine).

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('10.3.0.1', username='user', password='password')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('rsync -rav pi@10.3.0.1:path/to/file ~/')

for line in stdout:
    print '... ' + line.strip('\n')

client.close()
```